# Does StanfordNLP have a problem with adverbs?

Tags: computational-linguistics, adjectives, adverbs

I suspect not, and I'm being dumb, but ...

```
Usain ran quickest.
```

is parsed (https://corenlp.run) as

```
NNP VBZ JJS.
```

Why JJS (Adjective, superlative) and not RBS (Adverb, superlative)?

Using extended dependencies I get

```
dep: advmod, 
dependentGloss: quickest, 
governorGloss: ran
```

yet the manual (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) says

> An adverb modifier of a word is a (non-clausal) adverb or adverb-headed phrase that serves to modify the meaning of the word

Would be very grateful for an explanation of where I'm going wrong.

Comment: "Quickest" is an adverb here. The adverb "quick" is formed by conversion from the adjective "quick", and then the inflections are added to give "quicker and "quickest", both adverbs.

Comment: @BillJ  So you're agreeing that the parser is wrong here? Any idea how general a problem this is?

Comment: I can't comment on anything other than the fact that in your particular example, "quickest" is an adverb, not an adjective.